# Netbeans doesn't allow to clear git markup in "do not modify" area

Tags: java, git, netbeans

while merging a git branch containing UI interface of java swing (netbeans), a merge conflict created a markup on netbeans "do not modify" section(where all the swing components are declared by netbeans).

Netbeans doesn't allow me to modify anything on this section. Can some one suggest a way to clear this markup?

Please see the screen shot representing "dummyMahesh" branch merge conflict markup

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click the file and choose Git->Resolve Conflicts. Resolve them there and commit changes.